# Session Keys - MSDN - Microsoft

Tags: c++, encryption, msdn

I 'am working on an application that protect  files by encrypt it with `CryptEncrypt()` and use a session key, from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
I can't find out what session it's talking about . Is that means that if some one else takes my encrypted file to another machine (or on the same machine but different user) can not decrypted it even he has the password?

Can any one help me to clarify his point please.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that means that if some one else takes my encrypted file to another
>   machine (or on the same machine but different user) can not decrypted
>   it even he has the password?

No,

It's common to generate the session key for both the encryption and decryption by generating a hash which matches a passphrase:

```
// Hash in the password data. 
if(!CryptHashData( m_hHash, (BYTE *) m_strPassphrase.c_str(), (DWORD) m_strPassphrase.length(), 0)) 
{
    //  ...
}

// Derive a session key from the hash object. 
if(!CryptDeriveKey( m_hCryptProv, ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, m_hHash, KEYLENGTH, &m_hKey))
{ 
    //...
}
```

`m_hKey` can now be used for encryption/decryption.

```
CryptEncrypt( m_hKey, NULL, bEOF, 0, m_pBlockBuffer, &dwCount, m_dwBufferLen)
```

or ..

```
CryptDecrypt( m_hKey, 0, bEOF, 0, m_pBlockBuffer, &dwCount)
```

Comment: thank you @Benj, ok the session key should be the same for both,  my question is: it will be the same key if the user or the machine was different?

Comment: Yes, it's not tied to the user/computer.

Comment: Ok @Benj I thought it is, thanks any way I appreciate your help.